# why cryptogen does not creating the keysstore folder

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

i am using the cryptogen 1.4.0 version, its does not create the keystore folder inside the msp. please suggest some solution for this. what i am trying to achieve here is, using the cryptogen tool create the certificate and run the fabric CA server using the offline generated certificate by using docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes more sense to use openssl for that purpose.

Write your suitable csr.cnf (change dn and alt_names values):

```
[req]
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn
x509_extensions = x509_ext

[dn]
CN = mydomain.com
C = US
ST = New York
L = New York
O = MyOrg
OU = MyDepartment

[x509_ext]
basicConstraints=critical, CA:TRUE, pathlen:2
keyUsage=critical, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = mydomain.com
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
```

And then generate the key and the certificate:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout -out ca-key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem -days 7300 -config csr.cnf
```

And then use ca-cert.pem and ca-key.pem in your CA.

Anyway, Fabric-CA itself generates the certificate according to your fabric-ca-server-config.yaml parameters on first run if it does not exist.